# How do I resize the total width of a 2016 microsoft access report?

Tags: ms-access, resize, ms-access-reports

## Problem

I seem to be in a bind for a seemingly simple Access operation:
[image]

The closest options related to adjusting the width of a report (that I found) are:

## 1. Adjusting the width of [individual columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/modify-edit-or-change-a-report-2837aea7-0ee5-4c81-9f0f-5cf324c2c3bd#bmcrmlv) in design view or layout view:

[image]

which does not mention entire width

## 2.Attempting to resize the width in the Report Properties table:

[image]

[image]

which causes the width to default to 13.4792

## 3. Selecting from various presets in the Page Setup tab

[image]

which has no options for customization

## Question

Is there a way to customize the entire width of a 2016 Microsoft Access Report?

Comment: The width property will not change to less than is possible to accommodate existing controls in the report. Move or resize the controls first and then change the width. You can more easily change the width via mouse by dragging the right edge of the report (in any section). The cursor will change to the resize cursor when you hover over the right edge.

Comment: The issue I found here was a blank control that was not immediately visible in the design view.  Deleting this control solved the issue.

Comment: For me the issue was that the elements where too close to the edges of the report so Access won't allow me to change the report's width. Moving all of the elements to the center and then modifiying the width worked for me.